# Menu loaded by AJAX from the PHP back-end

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a menu in the Index page, i already have a code but i want to change the Url for more specific ones.

Now its show

> http://adrianalegria.com/#page1

but i want

> http://adrianalegria.com/News

there are 7 pages in the menu.

Here is the code in the `index`:

```
<ul id="app-menu">
       <li  >
        <a href="#page1" >News</a>
       </li>
       <li >
        <a href="#page2" >Dates</a>
       </li>
       <li >
        <a  href="#page3" >Biography</a>
       </li>
       <li >
        <a  href="#page4" >Discography</a>
       </li>
       <li >
        <a  href="#page5" >Social</a>
       </li>
       <li >
        <a  href="#page6" >Radio</a>
       </li>
       <li >
        <a href="#page7" >Contact</a>
       </li>

     </ul>
     <div id="pageContent"></div>
```

Here is the Js:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    checkURL();
    $('ul li a').click(function (e){

            checkURL(this.hash);

    });

    //filling in the default content
    default_content = $('#pageContent').html();


    setInterval("checkURL()",250);

});

var lasturl="";

function checkURL(hash)
{
    if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;

    if(hash != lasturl)
    {
        lasturl=hash;

        // FIX - if we've used the history buttons to return to the homepage,
        // fill the pageContent with the default_content

        if(hash=="")
        $('#pageContent').html(default_content);

        else
        loadPage(hash);
    }
}


function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#page','');

    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page='+url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Here the PHP:

```
if(!$_POST['page']) die("0"); 

$page = (int)$_POST['page'];

if(file_exists('subCat/'.$page.'.html')) 
echo file_get_contents('subCat/page_'.$page.'.html');
```

Thanks, is my first question, hope i can learn from all of you!!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through javascript pushState

Example

```
function processAjaxData(response, urlPath){
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response.html;
     document.title = response.pageTitle;
     window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", urlPath);
 }
```

Comment: What should i type in "content". i don´t how to link the js with my menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use `history.pushState()`

JS

```
$('ul li a').click(function (e){

        history.pushState({}, "", $(this).html());
        checkURL(this.hash);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="app-menu">
       <li  >
        <a href="page1" >News</a>
       </li>
       <li >
        <a href="page2" >Dates</a>
       </li>
       <li >
        <a  href="page3" >Biography</a>
       </li>
       <li >
        <a  href="page4" >Discography</a>
       </li>
       <li >
        <a  href="page5" >Social</a>
       </li>
       <li >
        <a  href="page6" >Radio</a>
       </li>
       <li >
        <a href="page7" >Contact</a>
       </li>

     </ul>
     <div id="pageContent"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li a').on('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = 'page='+ $(this).attr('href');         

        $.get(url, data, function(resultData){
            $('#pageContent').html(default_content);
            window.history.pushState({"pageTitle":"New Title"},"", $(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });
});
```